# Show Hide function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I want to open and close these lists with a single javascript function.
I don't want to write more than one javascript function for each list.
How can I do? The above are my codes

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".close").click(function(){
     $(".content").toggle("slow");
   });
 });
```

```css
.close {padding:0 5px;margin-left:10px;cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  Contents
  <span class="close">hide</span>
  <div  class="content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  Contents
  <span class="close">hide</span>
  <div  class="content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share your CSS?

Comment: .close{padding:0 5px;margin-left:10px;cursor:pointer;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jQuery` function [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to toggle on your `element` which is next to the `span` (hide)

In jQuery `$(this)` refers to the `element` we have `clicked` on and then we get the `next()` element which is your `.content` class to toggle slow on that.

This way. You do have to write the `code` again and again.

**Live Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".close").click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.close {
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Contents<span class="close">hide</span>
  <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  Contents<span class="close">hide</span>
  <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @FurkanÇetin happy to help. Please accept my answer by clicking the grey check-mark in my answer. Thanks

Comment: @FurkanÇetin I would recommend you to uniquely identify your lists for any future implementations and get a better and clear overview of your DOM.

Comment: @Sanguinary Classes can be repeated for multiple elements. and `$(this)` helps us what is being clicked on. OP code is good as it is.

Comment: This implementation works for this very specific example, but it relies on the button being the sibling to the list. This behaviour is not clear at first glance and it would be much safer to separately identify the elements.

Comment: @Ollie As i said classes can use for multiple element in a DOM. So even this way works as long as we are using using right jQuery function to work on those element. for this example OP code is good since my goal was not change the HTML.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Yes, agreed. This code works for this specific example. But in general it is good practice to try and think of edge cases and future-proofing scenarios. The show/hide buttons will cease to work as soon as they are moved within the page.

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work separately for each list, there has to be some kind of unique identifier so jQuery knows which list it should close when it is clicked.

Try something like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    Contents<span class="close" data-target="#list-1">hide</span>
    <div  class="content" id="list-1">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    Contents<span class="close" data-target="list-2">hide</span>
    <div  class="content" id="list-2">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".close").click(function(){
    var closeBtn = $(this)
    $(closeBtn.data('target')).toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: This would be the right approach. Seems like OP just forgot to uniquely identify the lists.

Comment: @Sanguinary No point here adding the data-attributes since classes can be repeated for multiple elements. and `$(this)` helps us what is being clicked on.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping The data attributes create the semantic link between the button and the list that the button shows/hides. Not individually identifying them relies on other mechanics such as checking for the sibling of the button, but this functionality then breaks the second you want to move the button to a different location.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want your close spans to just toggle the div that they are related to, or? In that case you can modify your JS like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".close").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".content").toggle("slow");
  });
});
```